# Parallel.For thread creation

Tags: c#, performance, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am using a parallel.for set up:

```
Parallel.For(0, 4, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, j =>
```

I am expecting it to create 4 worker threads, however the concurrency visualizer only shows 3 worker threads are being used. i have tried to use max degree of parallelism and processor affinity, however under each scenario only 3 worker threads are used, not 4.  Is there an obvious answer to why this is happening?  cheers

Comment: Are you sure you're not forgetting the thread where you run this code? That counts as one of those 4 threads, but it may not be a worker thread (depending on how you decide what that means).

Answer (score 1):

It is as it says `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, so it won't go above that but it won't use more than deemed necessary either.

This is what it says on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> By default, For and ForEach will utilize however many threads the underlying scheduler provides, so changing MaxDegreeOfParallelism from the default only limits how many concurrent tasks will be used.`

Comment: Thats how i understood it.  However, i am comparing an F# version of the same algorithm, run under the same conditions. the F# version always uses 4 threads, whereas the C# version always uses 3 which i find odd...

Comment: If you want 4 threads then use 4 threads. Create tasks inside a normal `For` loop. (BTW if this algorithm does not finish quickly you should mark the tasks LongRunning)

Comment: This still does not explain the behavior. Nobody is questioning that the behavior is legal, but *why*?

Comment: Where is the F# code you mentioned? Are you perhaps comparing different things? Even if you use Parallel.For in both cases, are the data the same?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, I can't remember where I read it, but it uses the thread pool underneath, and it just takes the tasks as there is processor power to do so.
Though it sound strange that there is a difference between C# and F#.

In theory it should also depend on the processor cores available. If there is only one core, then there is no need to spin up more than one thread.

If you want to force it to use 4 you can write your own scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you only can specify the maximum, not the actual number of threads. If you have four available cores, and the workload is nontrivial, all four **will** run in parallel as the thread you started the `For` from is also used to execute workitems.

In addition, `Parallel.For` may chunk your input range. It probably won't for four items, but if you're concerned, you can schedule 4 items at once with `Parallel.Invoke()`.

Answer (score 0):

Parralel.For has no idea how much irritations you will put to it, its flexible, it handles thread queues and at runtime its decided what available core is receiving a certain work-thread from threadque. A core might not be available as it is not only your code running on a windows machine. Or a core might still be bussy on a previous workload you gave it.

Here more in-depth info http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/26/parallelism-in-net-part-5-partitioning-of-work/